# Load a JavaScript module, store function result on variable and then console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam, node-modules

I'm new to JavaScript/Node.js and I'm trying to learn Asynchronous calls and callbacks.

I wrote the following code (steamid64.js):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var username = 'yllanos';

function getSteamID64(URL) {
  rp(URL)
      .then(function (xml) {
          parseString(xml, { explicitArray : false, ignoreAttrs : true, trim : true }, function(err, result){
          json = result;
      });
      console.log(json["profile"]["steamID64"]);

      })
      .catch(function (reason) {
        console.error("%s; %s", reason.error.message, reason.options.url);
        console.log("%j", reason.response.statusCode);
        return reason.error.message;
      });
}

exports.get = getSteamID64;

getSteamID64("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" + username +  "/?xml=1");
```

The module code goes to Steam, grabs the XML for this user, converts it to JSON and only using the customURL, I can console-log the SteamID64.

But I don't really want to console-log the result from my module. What I want now is to require the code above from another script (test.js), store the result in a variable and then do something else. For example, I could console-log from this external script (test.js).

So please how do I do that? I'm suspecting I should somehow export the JSON value that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just return the promise. Your steamid64.js module should look like this

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

var username = 'yllanos';

module.exports = function getSteamID64(URL) {
  return rp(URL)
    .then(function (xml) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        parseString(xml, {
          explicitArray : false,
          ignoreAttrs : true,
          trim : true
        }, function(err, result){
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(result);
          }
        });
      });
    });
}
```

Then in test.js

```
var getSteamID64 = require('steamdid64');

getSteamID64("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" + username +  "/?xml=1")
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function (reason) {
    console.error("%s; %s", reason.error.message, reason.options.url);
    console.log("%j", reason.response.statusCode);
    return reason.error.message;
  });
```

Comment: I ended up using this suggestion, but with slight modifications.  So the final code looks like this:

Answer (score 0):

You can return the request-promise from getSteamId64() and pass to module.exports so it can be called by require() on another script. But you have to access that value in the other script like a promise as well.

The original code you posted with minor alterations:

```
function getSteamID64(URL, cb) {
  return rp(URL)
      .then(function (xml) {
          parseString(xml, { explicitArray : false, ignoreAttrs : true, trim : true }, function(err, result){
          json = result;
      });
      return json["profile"]["steamID64"];
      })
      .catch(function (reason) {
        console.error("%s; %s", reason.error.message, reason.options.url);
        console.log("%j", reason.response.statusCode);
        return reason.error.message;
      });
}

module.exports = getSteamID64("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" + username +  "/?xml=1");
```

and the other script like this:

```
var steamid = require('./steamid64.js');

steamid.then(function(x){
    console.log("steamid:"+x);
});
```

Comment: I'll test and report back

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using gabesoft's suggestion. Final code looks like this:

(steamid64.js):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

module.exports = function getSteamID64(URL) {
  return rp(URL)
    .then(function (xml) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        parseString(xml, {
          explicitArray : false,
          ignoreAttrs : true,
          trim : true
        }, function(err, result){
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(result);
          }
        });
      });
});
}
```

and then (test.js):

```
var getSteamID64 = require('./steamid64');

var username = 'yllanos';

getSteamID64("http://steamcommunity.com/id/" + username +  "/?xml=1")
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result["profile"]["steamID64"]);
  })
  .catch(function (reason) {
    console.error("%s; %s", reason.error.message, reason.options.url);
    console.log("%j", reason.response.statusCode);
    return reason.error.message;
  });
```

What an elegant solution, thanks guys.